# How do I prevent Datebox from affecting other input elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datebox

I currently have a form that has a bunch of input elements in it.  I want to use Datebox's calendar feature for the input date.

My problem is that the CSS and JS that Datebox uses affects other input elements on the form.  What is the best way to prevent Datebox's CSS affect other input forms?

Here's a [jsFiddle link.  (click here)](http://tinyurl.com/d4fvs8k)

Comment: Please post the CSS that you're having difficulties with.

Comment: Rob, it's the standard  CSS and JS files that comes along with Datebox [(click Here)](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/install.html).  The default behavior is that its JS files literally edits all the input elements on the html file.  However, I only want it affecting one specific input element.

Comment: I don't see what selectors they are using that would be common to all your input elements. Do you have a jsfiddle or something I could look at?

Comment: Hey Rob, here's the jsfiddle [(click here)](http://jsfiddle.net/ayjay/5z9Qm/3/).  Note that there are 7 enxternal files (CSS and JS).

Answer (score 0):

It appears it's the jquery mobile css that you're including doing the styling, not the datepicker. You could reset your input styles, though it's possible you don't want the jquery mobile stylesheet.